# Nasty effect on drop down menu using jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am putting up a sort of drop down menu, obviuosly I'd like my sub menu items to stay hidden until the user hovers on the appropriate element and make them show. My problem is I get this nasty fade in/fade out effect and I cannot get it to work, can anyone please help me sort out this issue? [You can find my code here](http://jsfiddle.net/9umKx/).

HTML code:

```
<nav id="mainNav">
    <ul>
        <li class="topMenu"><a href="#">Section #1</a></li>
        <li class="topMenu"><a href="#">Section #2</a></li>
        <li class="topMenu"><a href="#">Section #3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item #1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item #2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item #3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="topMenu"><a href="#">Section #4</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item #1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item #2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item #3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item #4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item #5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="topMenu"><a href="#">Section #5</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item #1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item #2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="topMenu"><a href="#">Section #6</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

​

CSS

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

div#menu {
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff0078;
}

div#menu nav#mainNav a {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
    color: #e4e4e4;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
}

div#menu nav#mainNav ul li {
    top: 17px;
    left: 25px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

div#menu nav#mainNav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    width: 150px;
}

div#menu nav#mainNav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #000;
}

div#menu nav#mainNav ul li ul li:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0078;
}

div#menu nav#mainNav ul li ul li a {
    display: block;
}​
```

JS Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menuItems = $('div#menu nav#mainNav ul').find('li.topMenu');

    menuItems.on('mouseover', function() {
        var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
        $(this).find('ul').fadeIn();
    });

    menuItems.on('mouseout', function() {
        var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
        $(this).find('ul').fadeOut();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Please add your code to your OP; [questions should be fully self-contained](http://sscce.org).  Otherwise, when the fiddle goes dead your question is meaningless.

Comment: `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` are more like what you want.

Comment: You write <li><a href="#">SubMenu Item #1</a></li> but may be you could simplify it to <li>SubMenu Item #1</li> since you're not specifying a URL in your href anyway.

Comment: @frenchie well the `<a href="#"> ... </a>` is there because I actually need to link the list item to an URL.

Comment: @haunted85: ok for the <a> then:)

Comment: As long as you move the mouse on the top menu item, the one that triggers the animation, it works fine, but if you try to move the cursor on one of the sub menu items, then the animation gets messed up it's kinda like the mouse launches fadeIn and fadeOut because in order to get from a list item to another it enters and leaves _hot spots_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you are animating properties you should always stop previous running animations, otherwise you get *nasty effects*.

See new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/9umKx/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menuItems = $('div#menu nav#mainNav ul').find('li.topMenu');

    menuItems.on('mouseover', function() {
        var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
        $(this).find('ul').stop().fadeIn();
    });

    menuItems.on('mouseout', function() {
        var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
        $(this).find('ul').stop().fadeOut();
    });
});​
```

Comment: I would even add that instead of .fadeIn(), you should use .fadeTo() like this: $(this).find('ul').stop().fadeTo('medium', 100); Position your mouse on section 5 and go real fast to section 4 and real fast to the first submenu of section 4. Use fadeTo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menuItems = $('div#menu nav#mainNav ul').find('li.topMenu');

    menuItems.hover(
        function() {
            var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
            $(this).find('ul').fadeIn();
        },
        function() {
            var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
            $(this).find('ul').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

​

Comment: instead of `menuItems.on` you should try `menuItems.hover`. http://jsfiddle.net/Vz6QH/